# Google docs embedded document not showing until resize?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, iframe, document, google-docs

I have a problem in which **sometimes** (not clear when exactly), displaying an embedded document with `docs.google.com` does not show the document until I resize the browser window.

Grab some popcorn, here's a movie that shows the problem:

[image]

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<iframe runat="server" id="frame" style="width:100%;height:600px;border:0;"></iframe>
```

C# Code begind (in `Page_Load` method):

```
frame.Attributes["src"] = "https://docs.google.com/gview?url=https://example.com/1.doc&embedded=true";
```

I tried reproducing it by browsing directly to `https://docs.google.com/gview?url=https://example.com/1.doc&embedded=true` but it never happens this way.

**Note**: Sometimes the document is never displayd at all, as if it was never loaded, and the iFrame remains totaly blank.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: did you try to set a width in pixel? for example 500px

Comment: @Saeed No help - fixed `width` same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to setup a default document size.  This is what I do to print envelopes from Google Docs

```
 var envelope10={};
  envelope10[DocumentApp.Attribute.PAGE_HEIGHT]=296;
  envelope10[DocumentApp.Attribute.PAGE_WIDTH]=684;
  envelope10[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Calibri';
  envelope10[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 18;
  envelope10[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;
  envelope10[DocumentApp.Attribute.LINE_SPACING]=1;
```